# When is electric flux zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

While studying about electric flux, I came across a problem which asked to calculate net electric flux through uncharged closed hemisphere. The answer was 0. But electric flux is amount of field line passing through a surface, but field lines were passing through the hemisphere.

When I searched about the question I found some answer saying that since number of field line entering and existing the hemisphere is equal net flux is zero. But then if we consider a plane, the number of electric field line coming in from one side of plane is equal to the number of field line existing the plane. But in this case net flux is not zero.

So when and why is electric flux zero and what does it actually mean?

Comment: Is the hemisphere a closed surface or an open surface?

Comment: You have tu consider the flux or field lines  in direction of the normal of your surface, a plain has only one normal, the sphere has left and right different orientation of the normal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Gauss Law we say , The Electric Flux is equal to a charge enclosed by a closed surface divided by permittivity of free space (if the system is in free space),Here closed meaning having a well defined inside or outside and the example you mention "But then if we consider a plane, the number of electric field line coming in from one side of plane is equal to the number of field line exiting the plane. But in this case net flux is not zero."

Inside an uncharged closed hemisphere the net charge is 0 so the flux is 0. The Plane does not have a well defined inside (Not outside as its a 2d structure so volume is 0 but it does exist)  so here it would only be the field lines entering the surface and it does not exiting as it doesn't have an inside Mainly no volume enclosed)! Hence its non zero in this case

Answer (score 0):

Gauss is a three-dimensional law with a closed surface **enclosing** a volume so you cannot consider a plane as it does not enclose a volume.